# include parameters with strings in a list

Tags: python, loops, boolean, custom-lists

I have a list of cli commands for a firewall that are passed via netmiko.(https://github.com/ktbyers/netmiko) function.

The problem is that some of the strings commands contain additional parameters e.g. 
send_command_timing("Show system info, delay_factor=1, max_loops=150, strip_prompt=True,strip_command=True)

Is there a way I can add the entire command to a list including the parameters ?

```
list_a =[ "Do_Something","Do_Something|else","Do_Altogether_Something_Else |"]

        for command in list_a :
            matching = [s for s in list_a if "|" in s]
            if command == matching:
                query = connection.send_command_timing(matching,delay_factor=1, max_loops=150, strip_prompt=True,strip_command=True)
                print (query)
```

Im sorry if my question was a little ambiguous. Please let me know if this is better

Comment: I have read your question multiple times and still do not understand what you are trying to do. Please take the time to make a clear question.

Comment: I have tried as best I could to edit your question into what I think you were trying to ask. If my edits were wrong, let me know and I'll roll them back. If I am wrong, please try editing the question yourself, to clarify exactly what you mean.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not 100% sure what you're trying to do, but here's my best attempt at a solution. From what I gather from the question (and correct me if I'm wrong), you have a list of strings, where each of these string is a command, followed by arguments to the command; i.e. they follow the following format: `'command|arg0|arg1|arg2'`. The reason I think this is because your question says:

> The problem is that some of the strings commands also include arguments in them which are separated by a vertical bar from the actual command.

Now, you also say you want to separate the arguments from the command. Here's a function that would do that for you, given an `input_string`.

```
def separate_args_and_command(input_string):
    command_and_args = input_string.split('|')
    return command_and_args[0], command_and_args[1:]
```

This function returns a tuple that has your command, followed by a list of your args. Here's a simple example:

```
>>> separate_args_and_command('my_command|my_arg0|my_arg1')
('my_command', ['my_arg0', 'my_arg1'])
```

Here's an example of how you would use this function for your question:

```
list_a = ["command0|arg0", "command1","command2|arg0|arg1|arg2"]
for command_and_args in list_a:
    command, arguments = separate_args_and_command(command_and_args)

    # Now you have your command, and your arguments separated. If there are no
    # arguments, the arguments variable will be an empty list.
```

Comment: I think this is hitting in the write direction. Will work with this to see if it gets me what I was looking for thanks.